# Uncode WordPress theme, WooCommerce image flip/change on hover

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, woocommerce

I'm using the Uncode WordPress theme and I have a small shop part.
I want to use some kind of image change on hover for my products, however the Magni Image Flip WooCommerce plugin doesn't work with Uncode for some reason.

Are there any other options available or is there a custom way to achieve the desired effect?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should work fine. Did you add images to the product gallery for each product so the plugin can flip the images from that source?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes all products already have multiple images in the gallery. This is the (now not in use) shop page: https://moldbrothers.nl/en/shop/